# simplexml parser php iteration

Tags: php, xml

I cannot figure out how does this thing work. I followed Instruction from PHP Doc.

Here is my code:

```
$xmlfile = simplexml_load_file($xmlurl) or die("Cannon get.");
```

The file contains following schema:

```
<PriceResult>
 <QueryStatus>
 </QueryStatus>
 <InputData>
 </InputData>
 <Producers/>
 <Prices>
   <Price>
   </Price>
   <Price>
     <PartId>13580448730</PartId>
     <BrandId>11</BrandId>
     <Brand>BERU</Brand>
     <PartNumber>Z226</PartNumber>
     <PartNumberShort>Z226</PartNumberShort>
     <PartDescriptionRus/>
     <Price>8.90</Price>
     <Currency>EUR</Currency>
     <Quantity>0</Quantity>
     <QuantityType>EQUAL</QuantityType>
     <PriceLogo>GLIR</PriceLogo><Weight/>
     <PriceDescrShort>Европейский поставщик запчастей</PriceDescrShort>
     <PriceDescrLong>Европейский поставщик запчастей</PriceDescrLong>    
     <DeliveryType>LOCAL</DeliveryType>
     <DeliveryDays>17</DeliveryDays>
     <PriceChangeDate>2015-01-05 10:27:05</PriceChangeDate>    
     <DamagedFlag>N</DamagedFlag>
     <UsedFlag>N</UsedFlag>
     <OriginalFlag>N</OriginalFlag>
     <OldPartNumberFlag>N</OldPartNumberFlag>
     <Group>0</Group><GroupDescr/>
   </Price>
<Price>
</Price>
<Price>
</Price>
</PriceResult>
```

I did that before, but now I forgot. So how could I iterate XML through Price in Prices to be able get data like this:

```
foreach ($xmlfile->children() as $item){
    print($item->BrandId);
}
```

and Ill get all the brands, or $item->PartId - all the part? e.t.c to all

Comment: I'm not developing in php but I can't see a closing </prices> in your xml.

Comment: sorry, fixed. now u should see

Answer (score 0):

```
$xmlfile = simplexml_load_file($xmlurl) or die("Cannon get.");
```

Then
    $xxx= $xmlfile->xxx;
    $yyy = $xmlfile->yyy;
    $zzz = $xmlfile->zzz;

After all, it's more simple to show data like this

```
echo $xxx;
```

And where is your "->children() " ?

Comment: I didn't get that. $xmlfile objects contains inside a lot of 'Price' entities.
I need to iterate through each Price entity and get all data.
IDK somehow 

`foreach($xmlfile->Prices as $Price) print($Price->BrandId, $Price->PartId) e.t.c.`